# XSLT validation error javax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException:

Tags: xslt

i'm having this error when i tried to validate my XSLT

```
javax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException: 
  javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: 
  javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: 
    A node test that matches either NCName:* or QName was expected.
```

this is my XSLT

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"><xsl:output method="html" />
<xsl:template match="\Apps">
<html>
<head> <title>Apps List</title>
<link rel="StyleSheet" href="table_style.css" type="text/css"/>
<style type="text/css">
body {font-family: Helvetca;}
h1 { color : Grey;}
h2 {color : Blue;}</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1> Apps List: <xsl:value-of select="\@List_Type" /></h1>
<p>This is a list of all currently hot apps:</p>
<xsl:for-each select="\App">
<xsl:if test="\App\@installed == true">
<h2 style="color:Green;"><xsl:value-of select="\App\app_name" />(instaled)</h2>
</xsl:if>
<xsl:otherwise>
<h2><xsl:value-of select="\App\app_name" /></h2>
</xsl:otherwise>
<p style="font-style:bold;">App info:</p>
<table id="#gradient-style">
<tr><th>Category:</th><td><xsl:value-of select="\App\catogry" /></td></tr>
<tr><th>Verdion:</th><td><xsl:value-of select="\App\version" /></td></tr>
<tr><th>Description:</th><td><xsl:value-of select="\App\description" /></td></tr>
<tr><th>App Reviews:</th><td><xsl:for-each select="\App\reviews\review">
<span style="font-style:bold;"><xsl:value-of select="\App\reviews\review\reviewer_name" /></span>
| <xsl:value-of select="\App\reviews\review\review_date" /> 
| <xsl:value-of select="\App\reviews\review\review_Time" /><br/>
<span style="font-style:bold;">Rating:</span>
<xsl:value-of select="string(\App\reviews\review\rating" /> <br/>
<xsl:value-of select="\App\reviews\review\ontent" /><br/>
----------------------------------------------------------
</xsl:for-each>
</td></tr>
</table>
</xsl:for-each>
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

this is the XML that tried with

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="ShdenXSLT.xsl"?> 
<Apps xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/1999/XMLSchema-instance" List_Type="new releases" >
<App device_type="tablet" app_id="120">
<app_name>Meeting Manager</app_name>
<catogry>LifeStyle </catogry>
<catogry>Bussnisse </catogry>
<version>1.0</version>
<description>This app is about managing the bussnisse meeting</description>
<reviews>
<review>
<reviewer_name>Shaden</reviewer_name>
<review_date>2012-02-13</review_date>   
<review_time>11:35:02</review_time>
<content>it was a useful app</content>
<rating>4.5</rating>
</review>         
<review>
<reviewer_name>Mohamed</reviewer_name>
<review_date>2012-03-01</review_date>
<review_time>12:15:00</review_time>
<content>i really loved this app</content>
<rating>5.0</rating>
</review>
</reviews>
</App>

<App device_type="tablet" app_id="100">
<app_name>ToDoList</app_name>
<catogry>LifeStyle </catogry>
<version>3.4.2</version>
<description>a simple To Do List applecation</description>
<reviews>
<review>
<reviewer_name>Fahad</reviewer_name>
<review_date>2010-02-05</review_date>
<review_time>09:40:55</review_time>
<content>nice app</content>
<rating>4.0</rating>
</review>
</reviews>
</App>
</Apps>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using backslash (`\`) as your XPath separator (i.e. `<xsl:value-of select="\@List_Type" />`), which is incorrect.  It should be a forward slash (`/`)

Comment: yah i notice that later i fixed it but nothing changed